# Google analytics cross domain issue

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, universal-analytics, web-analytics, event-tracking

was struggling with GA cross-domain tracking (for leadpages service)

Below is what i have got

Original page is
https://my.leadpages.net

has the following tracking code

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-5398591-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', [ 'https://drdaniel.leadpages.co']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**And the second domain page is**

https://drdaniel.leadpages.co

and has the follow tracking code

```
     <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-5398591-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['https://my.leadpages.net']);
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Was trying not to use https:// but that did not give any results. Please, say what I am doing wrong here. Also excluded refferals
Thanks

Comment: One obvious issue is that you included the protocol in the linker configuration when it really should be the hostname only.

Comment: it is not an issue, I wrote that tried to do this without protocol, does not work either

Comment: It might not be the only issue, but since the documentation says you should use the hostname without protocol it's certainly _one_ issue.

Comment: Also you might specify what your problem actually is. Does cross domain tracking not work or do you not receive hits at all (btw. https://my.leadpages.net/ does not seem to have GA tracking at all) ?

Comment: it is the certain url that has the tracking code. Documentation cannot help me as I do everyting like it says. I need someone who has experience in debugging such iisues